# Find a value in excel and print it

Tags: excel, powershell

I'm stuck with PowerShell once more. 
Here is my scenario:
I have an excel sheet with a report in it. Within the excel file there are two lines that I'm looking for

Total number of errors         =   0

Total number of fatal errors   =   0

The problem with these two lines is that the spaces after the "errors" may vary depending on the report.  Another issue is the number of errors (in this case 0) is in the same cell.

What I'm trying to do is find those two lines and return the number of errors.
Here is what my code looks like so far. I know it's missing some stuff and also not working. I tried lots of regular expressions with no luck.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you everyone in advance.

```
$File = "C:\test\setup.xlsx"
$Excel = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application
$Excel.visible = $true
$Workbook = $Excel.workbooks.open($file)
$Worksheets = $Workbooks.worksheets
$Worksheet = $Workbook.Worksheets.Item(1)
$Range = $Worksheet.UsedRange
$Keywords="fatal errors", "errors"
$Filter = "Total number of"+ ($(($Keywords|%{[RegEx]::Escape($_)}) -join "|"))
$Search = $Range.find($Filter)
IF($Search -match '\d[0]')
    {
    "No Errors found"
    "No fatal errors found"
    }
ELSE
    {
    "number of errors found = " $search
    "number of fatal errors found = " $search 
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I'll start off by saying that your regex is looking for "Total number offatal errors" or "Total number oferrors" because you have no space after 'of'. That alone might fix it.

```
"Total number of (?:fatal )?errors\s*=\s*(\d*)"
```

That's the RegEx I'll be using. See it in action here

To be honest I wouldn't rely on Excel to find it. I'd tell PowerShell to find it, and this is how I'd do it:

```
$File = "C:\test\setup.xlsx"
$Excel = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application
$Excel.visible = $true
$Workbook = $Excel.workbooks.open($file)
$Worksheets = $Workbooks.worksheets
$Worksheet = $Workbook.Worksheets.Item(1)
$Range = $Worksheet.UsedRange
$Errors = 0
$FatalErrors = 0
$Range.cells.value2 | Where{$_ -match "Total number of (?:fatal )?errors\s*=\s*(\d*)"} | ForEach{
    Switch($Matches[0]){
        {$_ -like "*fatal*"}{$FatalErrors+=$Matches[1];continue}
        default{$Errors+=$Matches[1]}
    }
}

If($Errors -gt 0){
    "Number of errors found = " + $Errors
}else{
    "No errors found"
}

If($FatalErrors -gt 0){
    "Number of errors found = " + $FatalErrors
}else{
    "No fatal errors found"
}
```

Results (accurate by the test spreadsheet I setup):

```
Number of errors found = 23
Number of errors found = 7
```

Changed cell values to have 3 spaces after error and set the number to 2, and set fatal errors to 0. Results:

```
Number of errors found = 2
No fatal errors found
```

**Edit:** Ok, so the Switch might be confusing I guess if you aren't familiar with it. It's another loop, and it works like this:

```
Switch(<array to loop through>){
    Condition  {Action if condition is true}
    Condition2 {Action if condition2 is true}
    default {Action to take if no conditions are true}
}
```

So in our case we have one condition that is checking to see if the cell in the Where statement contains the word 'fatal'. If it does it adds the matching text to the $FatalErrors variable. If it doesn't have fatal, then it goes to Default and adds the match to $Errors. The matching text being the number at the end of the string.

Comment: TheMadTechnician to the rescue :)
this works perfect. Would you mind explaining me whats going on here? I kind of lose it starting from the "Switch"
    $Range.cells.value2 | Where{$_ -match "Total number of     (?:fatal )?errors\s*=\s*(\d*)"} | ForEach{
    Switch($Matches[0]){
        {$_ -like "*fatal*"}{$FatalErrors+=$Matches[1];continue}
        default{$Errors+=$Matches[1]}

Comment: Hopefully that makes sense now.

Comment: It does makes sense but still confusing. I guess I have to play around to learn more. Thank you as always for your help.